# How to find an older version of Microsoft Office 365 for MacBook 10.11.6

Tags: office-365

The harddisk of the MacBook crashed. Now I want te re-install Office 365, but the latest version needs 10.12.0. My MacBook (medio 2009) has El Capitan 10.11.6. more is not possible. Who knows a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can find previous installers at

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac

If you go to that page, look for the installer for "16.15 (18070902)" and use that.

In case the page changes or doesn't exist in the future, here are the current links:

#### Release Notes:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-for-mac#july-2018-release

#### Installer Package

https://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/OfficeMac/Microsoft_Office_2016_16.15.18070902_Installer.pkg

#### Verification Information

Size:

```
1797089465 bytes (1.79 GB)
```

md5 -r Microsoft_Office_2016_16.15.18070902_Installer.pkg

```
e580d202dca712c268c288b36576a89a Microsoft_Office_2016_16.15.18070902_Installer.pkg
```

shasum -a 256 -p Microsoft_Office_2016_16.15.18070902_Installer.pkg

```
2caa050dcc2a95f90f57449f9ab5b173437fa2580f282f4c1513a83918e49ffa ?Microsoft_Office_2016_16.15.18070902_Installer.pkg
```